# Without a jailbreak can iOS run python script?

Tags: python, ios, jailbreak

My application is written in Objective C, but I want let one module execute python script...

[kivy](http://www.kivy.org) seems can not do this. and I don't want to jailbreak...

anybody know how to run python script in a ios app called by oc function?

[run a simple python script in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276656/run-a-simple-python-script-in-ios) seems fit my question, but i don't know where to get the python.h and libpython.a.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run python on your non-jailbroken

example ipod touch or iphone with

python for ios: http://pythonforios.com/ (paid)

and python math: https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/python-math/id429450202?mt=8 (free)

so it seams not impossible

but apps on non-jailbroken devices are flanged so this is a bit slow and it could crash on big scripts if you add python

real python on jailbreak is of course the best way

if you want to add python scripts on your objec-c app , I don't think apple let you make that or it will a waste of time and a issues

Comment: do you know kivy? it compile .py file to .pyo, then call .pyo file in object-c app. and apple passed that app. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/deflectouch/id505729681?mt=8 , maybe i  can do like that.