# Run python scripts in iOS app

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to run python scripts in ios app. I found this question [run a simple python script in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276656/run-a-simple-python-script-in-ios)
In answer he include Python.h

```
#include <Python.h>
```

Where I can get this file? In which library or framework? Compiler said me "Python.h file not found"

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.2, xCode 4.6
I have Python.framework in System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework and there Python.h

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script you are looking at is for OS X - not iOS. Sadly, iOS **does not** include the Python framework.

Comment: This is for iOS not OS X.  iOS doesn't include the Python framework.  You're referring to the OS X framework.

Comment: iOS does not include Python, but you can embed. Somehow the Pythonista app does this.