# Embed python in to iOS (iphone) app written in Objective-C/Swift/C/C++ (whatever language i can compile in Xcode and bridge to iOS)

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, xcode, pyobjc

**I Do Not Intend To Put The Project On The App Store**

- **Short Question** -  is there any up-to-date PyObjC tutorial for embedding python scripts into an **iOS app** written in Objective-C and/or swift? If not if there any up-to-date method for achieving the same goal?
- **Background**: I want to run a bunch python scripts in an objective-c ios app. I have tried a couple of things:

  1. I have tried using the python.framework, but i get a "could not build Python module" error. After googling for help, I realized that python.framework does not work on iOS - [Run python scripts in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687485/run-python-scripts-in-ios-app)
  2. PyObjC - For the sake of experimenting, I managed to get the generated *.plugin working on OS X. I followed this tutorial - https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/tutorials/embedded.html
     Using the same method on iOS, it fails to compile

Comment: The project is just for fun and not meant to go in the app store?

Comment: I dont intend to put the project in the app store. I just want to use it as a demo for the python engine

Comment: Important to note that, or you'll get a ton of people saying, it isn't allowed.

Comment: Thanks  Cameron, I just updated the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If anyone is ever interested in calling python from swift, here is some helpful material I found(used) -

- use the python framework - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2328/_index.html
- PyObjC (a little more challenging) -
- cobbal - https://github.com/cobbal/python-for-iphone
- python docs (you would need to make C-Swift bridhe)

Most of it is for Objective-c, but if you need to use swift you can easily just create an ObjC-Swift bridge (super-super easy) - Lookup the apple docs

I managed to get the first two methods working on an OS X app, but I got some architecture errors for iOS(not important). I've pushed the project aside for now, I have a ton I need to get done.

Hope this will be helpful for anyone interested :-)

Comment: Hi, I have exact case what you have described in question. Did you find solution to make it work in iOS project? If so, can you please guide me? I want to use this library in my project https://github.com/secnot/rectpack

Comment: Any updates on this? If you have a git with your progress that would be awesome. I've been thinking about converting python to C and loading that into iOS. I haven't had any luck with the methods you've listed